# Java: send string to input stream

Tags: java, inputstream

I try to send string to my `InputStream`:

```
String _source = "123";
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(_source.getBytes("UTF-8"));
tempLab2.readR(in);
            
String _source2 = "321";
in.read(_source2.getBytes());
_myClass.readR(in);
```

When I create new `ByteArrayInputStream` and set `_source` as an argument, then everything works well. My method readR does not wait any `\n` or `EOF` charapters and reads `123`.

> Please enter R:
>
> R: 123

`readR` method:

```
public void readR(InputStream inpSteram) {
    Scanner tScanner = new Scanner(inpSteram);
    System.out.println("Please enter R:");
    _R = tScanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("R: " + _R);
}
```

But if I send `_source2` with `in.read(_source2.getBytes())` so my `Scanner` is waiting and I see only

> Please enter R:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
in.read(_source2.getBytes());
```

does not add new info to the inputstream, instead it empties it, if there would have been more data. So the inputstream is exhausted.

You just need to create a new inputstream before the next call to readR. So:

```
String _source2 = "321";
in = new ByteArrayInputStream(_source2.getBytes("UTF-8"));
_myClass.readR(in);
```

Comment: Is there any way without creating a new ByteArrayInputStream?

Comment: No. Once you create a ByteArrayInputStream you cannot feed it with new bytes. You could change readR to accept a String and create the inputstream inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense:

```
String _source2 = "321";
in.read(_source2.getBytes());
```

`in.read()` reads bytes from `in`, and stores what it has read in the byte array passed as argument. So basically, the above code creates a three bytes-long array, fills it with 3 bytes, and then tries to read bytes from the input stream and fills the 3-bytes-long byte array with the result.

Comment: Okey, but you did not answer how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an InputStream for working with characters, use a Reader.

Also, in your second example, you are not doing what you think you are doing.  you are not adding the `_source2` bytes to the input stream.  you are instead attempting to re-use the original bytes from the original InputStream, which is now empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely obvious what you're after here, but when using the `Scanner` class, you can simply send a string straight to it like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

And so on.. This is assuming, of course, that you're taking input from the console.